# How can I view the list of available conference rooms in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Tags: outlook

How can I view the list of available conference rooms in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

For example, on the Microsoft Outlook web interface, one can view the list of available conference rooms:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of December 2018, the room finder is not yet implemented on Outlook for Android.

The following article [Compare Outlook for PC, Outlook on the web, and Outlook for iOS & Android](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/compare-outlook-for-pc-outlook-on-the-web-and-outlook-for-ios-android-b26a7bf5-0ac7-48ba-97af-984e0645dde5) lists the features available on different versions of Outlook. `Meeting room finder` feature is listed as `No` (meaning not available) on  both Android and iOS but available on Outlook for PC and Outlook on the web.